# Trying to decrypt an private key secure with a passphrase

Tags: node.js, encryption

I try with the crypto `nodejs` module. But I don't succeed to make it works.

```js
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import { RsaPrivateKey } from 'crypto';

const privateKey = crypto.privateDecrypt(rsaPrivateKey, Buffer.from('')).toString();
```

I got a passphrase. I need to do this so I can import my certificate inside AWS. Someone have an idea?

I know that we can do it in golang with

```golang
if x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock(block) {
  der, wrongPass := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, []byte(o.passphrase))
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: As it seems to be a "one time conversion" I recommend to use OpenSSL for this task. My encrypted file is named "privatekey_pkcs1_2048_aes256_123456.pem", so the complete command line is **openssl rsa -in privatekey_pkcs1_2048_aes256_123456.pem -out privatekey_pkcs1_2048_unencrypted.pem**, next you need to type in the passphrase, and you receive the unencrypted private key file "privatekey_pkcs1_2048_unencrypted.pem"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decryption is easily possible with the crypto module of NodeJS using the two functions [`crypto.createPrivateKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key) for importing the encrypted key and [`keyObject.export()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_keyobject_export_options) for exporting the unencrypted key:

```
crypto = require('crypto');

encryptedPkcs1 = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,B2FBBDCE627586CB04423335D9D4EC59

ekUVpHooHO3d5Ao0gTovipGK9DAP0MBXffEvBrtvcNcxhd9vaE6PsIxQPGwxnc/C
v9Y5RiClNwgZHtRol+i+QeZYLQHUQdOs3toymUgpIcN19IHyxU4C17PCWLZQpuVy
7hcD150dxkGv6Ai53QHIIl4Zybk6neBSbHpJtCnKjRMc6dNONpmFGqO/9SCmH/Bv
lHtPNZ9VsCDI67OO9fMQ3AqfpeGmCwJF8HgXf0nquQH1BJkZsYc4bq/xfGLFII0N
odWD1XEnwL4DWQ1r2wH0IvAXyVQUpwUmDeuDeeslQe9S5IERxovlFKIGsJnIrDLu
j420LLuiMjvj4Cipl91zZjlypsxCXgP7Ta8SDNNWo6yi0qAk1VbMAaeu2GsI6mn5
IUmGr0mkZsSxGFSc9614z+2aJjXEuX1jZ1q83nnZMTz0zEKu/0B6M5h+2B7kG5W1
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

encryptedKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
  key: encryptedPkcs1,
  passphrase: 'myPassword'})

decryptedKey = encryptedKey.export({
  format: 'pem',
  type: 'pkcs1',})
```

Note that in practice nowadays the key should not be smaller than 2048 bits for security reasons. The 512 bit key here is only used for testing.

The output is:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBPAIBAAJBAL2D8iI9YRKCxsqDrw9WDFddW+xD2FBx383pxiW4el8M2OangbWH
FzOf8Y8ZQiw5tfocUqTvMhOcS1gThT5zUusCAwEAAQJBAJjTO0IzPwF/ZjFPKa9z
U3ZsOcF4IIsWmUTivMAUWNImFS0XiecmhiOpdgjP4LQ5gkphcC7f9VYS6Xw4suen
ZOECIQDp3GtcMdHJzQKn4fDnmTStHeEVDoqvs2tVE/HaWoYhMQIhAM900ZGxJIxK
GYrdkGU2ETvvkyRH7JStGlj3dIJDGE7bAiEAiSIFmpRkLm+XJRbqiwRdzT3+JLjY
Plt5jvQZGC+JA6ECICzJB0TwfPdcN89mrXlsBqRtv9IhRM2D4SA7q4dDfMfpAiEA
s9/2kHpLVmtpEDyw+u4Qrgt6/xUR1B39nceE1bEBo+U=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I finally have been doing. Forget to take a look again here. It's exactly the same process I have now